# Как отрисовать 3D модель, чтобы были видны контур и резкие края / углы?

Tags: java, javafx, 3d

Я сейчас делаю приложение на JavaFX способное вывести 3d модель (.obj файлы) на экран, для этого использую `jimObjModelImporterJFX`. А в другом окне нужно получить видимый контур этой модели, т.е. те что человек воспринимает как края.

Не совсем понимаю как это сделать, ведь в Mesh я могу получить Points() в котором хранится массив float в последовательности x, y, z. И я не совсем понимаю как от туда выделить только видимые точки/ребра.

Что сейчас реализовано в программе:
[image: Что сейчас делает программ]
То что мне нужно получить:
[image: Что нужно получить]

Как я понимаю, то во втором окне нужно реализовать свой рендеринг модели и применять следующие правила: 
1. Ребро должно быть не перекрыто другими полигонами. 
2. Нормали к соседним ему граням имеют угол больше К радиан. 
3. Скалярные произведения нормалей к граням с осью Z камеры противоположны по знакам. Но я вот не со всем понимаю как реализовать эти пункты.

Или же, как мне это виделось, с модели что выводится на первом экране получить точки видимого контура и нарисовать этот контур самому на другом окне

Код приложения:

```
import com.interactivemesh.jfx.importer.ImportException;
import com.interactivemesh.jfx.importer.obj.ObjModelImporter;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point3D;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.DrawMode;
import javafx.scene.shape.MeshView;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class OutputModel extends Application {
    MeshView[] one;
    MeshView[] second;
    private double rotateX = 0;
    private double rotateY = 0;

    double cameraDistance = 450;
    double cameraX = 100;
    double cameraY = -300;

    private MeshView[] get3dModel() {
        ObjModelImporter objImporter = new ObjModelImporter();
        try {
            URL modelUrl = this.getClass().getResource("/teapot.obj");
            objImporter.read(modelUrl);
        } catch (ImportException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
        return objImporter.getImport();
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        one = get3dModel();
        Arrays.stream(one).forEach(it -> {
            it.setTranslateX(450);
            it.setTranslateY(-30);
            it.setTranslateZ(450);
            it.setScaleX(200.0);
            it.setScaleY(200.0);
            it.setScaleZ(200.0);
        });
        second = get3dModel();
        Arrays.stream(second).forEach(it -> {
            it.setTranslateX(450);
            it.setTranslateY(-30);
            it.setTranslateZ(450);
            it.setScaleX(200.0);
            it.setScaleY(200.0);
            it.setScaleZ(200.0);
            it.setDrawMode(DrawMode.LINE);
        });
        Stage secondStage = new Stage();
        Rotate rxBox = new Rotate(0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
        Rotate ryBox = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
        Rotate rzBox = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);

        // Add the Shapes and the Light to the Group
        Group rootTwo = new Group(second);
        rootTwo.setDepthTest(DepthTest.ENABLE);
        rootTwo.getTransforms().addAll(rxBox, ryBox, rzBox);
        // Create a Scene with depth buffer enabled
        Scene sceneSecond = new Scene(rootTwo, 400, 300, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        // Create a Camera to view the 3D Shapes
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);
        camera.setTranslateX(cameraX);
        camera.setTranslateY(cameraY);
        camera.setNearClip(0.1);
        camera.setFarClip(10000.0);
        camera.setTranslateZ(cameraDistance);

        PerspectiveCamera cameraTwo = new PerspectiveCamera(false);
        cameraTwo.setTranslateX(cameraX);
        cameraTwo.setTranslateY(cameraY);
        cameraTwo.setNearClip(0.1);
        cameraTwo.setFarClip(10000.0);
        cameraTwo.setTranslateZ(cameraDistance);
        // Add the Camera to the Scene
        sceneSecond.setCamera(cameraTwo);
        sceneSecond.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        // Add the Scene to the Stage
        secondStage.setScene(sceneSecond);
        // Set the Title of the Stage
        secondStage.setTitle("OutputWireframe");
        // Display the Stage
        secondStage.show();

        // Add the Shapes and the Light to the Group
        Group root = new Group(one);
        root.setDepthTest(DepthTest.ENABLE);
        root.getTransforms().addAll(rxBox, ryBox, rzBox);
        // Create a Scene with depth buffer enabled
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        Rotate rotationX = new Rotate(0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
        Rotate rotationY = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        root.getTransforms().addAll(rotationX, rotationY);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.UP)) {
                rotateY += 5;
                root.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
                root.setRotate(rotateY);
                rootTwo.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
                rootTwo.setRotate(rotateY);
            }
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.DOWN)) {
                rotateY -= 5;
                root.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
                root.setRotate(rotateY);
                rootTwo.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
                rootTwo.setRotate(rotateY);
            }
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.LEFT)) {
                rotateX -= 5;
                root.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
                root.setRotate(rotateX);
                rootTwo.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
                rootTwo.setRotate(rotateX);
            }
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.RIGHT)) {
                rotateX += 5;
                root.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
                root.setRotate(rotateX);
                rootTwo.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
                rootTwo.setRotate(rotateX);
            }
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.EQUALS)) {
                cameraDistance += 10;
                camera.setTranslateZ(cameraDistance);
                cameraTwo.setTranslateZ(cameraDistance);
            }
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.MINUS)) {
                cameraDistance -= 10;
                camera.setTranslateZ(cameraDistance);
                cameraTwo.setTranslateZ(cameraDistance);
            }
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.W)) {
                cameraY += 5;
                camera.setTranslateY(cameraY);
                cameraTwo.setTranslateY(cameraY);
            }
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.S)) {
                cameraY -= 5;
                camera.setTranslateY(cameraY);
                cameraTwo.setTranslateY(cameraY);
            }
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.A)) {
                cameraX -= 5;
                camera.setTranslateX(cameraX);
                cameraTwo.setTranslateX(cameraX);
            }
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.D)) {
                cameraX += 5;
                camera.setTranslateX(cameraX);
                cameraTwo.setTranslateX(cameraX);
            }
            sendMeshViews(cameraTwo);
        });

        // Add the Camera to the Scene
        scene.setCamera(camera);
        // Add the Scene to the Stage
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        // Set the Title of the Stage
        primaryStage.setTitle("OutputModel");
        // Display the Stage
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void sendMeshViews(PerspectiveCamera camera) {
        Point3D oz = new Point3D(camera.getTranslateX(), camera.getTranslateY(), camera.getTranslateZ()).normalize();
        Arrays.stream(second).parallel().forEach(it -> {
        });
        // TODO: 11.01.2017 написать обработку, чтобы передавать лишь видимые грани
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Контур такой же ширины как и линия Mesh у модели. Скорее по середке края модели, если я вас правильно понял.

Comment: Как я понимаю, то во втором окне нужно реализовать свой рендеринг модели и применять следующие правила: 1. Ребро должно быть не перекрыто другими полигонами. 2. Нормали к соседним ему граням имеют угол больше К радиан. 3. Скалярные произведения нормалей к граням с осью Z камеры противоположны по знакам. Но я вот не со всем понимаю как реализовать эти пункты.

Comment: @Kromster, не знаю примут ли такое, как я понял привиденные правила являются не рекомендацией, а обязательным условием

Comment: Уточните обязательность "правил" в вопросе. Если они именно такие, то ваша картинка с примером неверна (вероятно контур будет рисоваться и в местах острых углов, например, стык носика и тела чайника).

Comment: @Kromster Да, вы правы. Исправил описание вопроса. Добавил картинку, чтобы ни кого не путать

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать как это делает Blender. Выведите сначала модель сеткой, из толстых линий. Поверх сетки наложите модель. Поскольку линии сетки толстые, модель закроет все кроме контура. Если нужен только контур - наложите модель, покрашенную черным

Comment: Советую вам создать собственный вопрос (про отрисовку внешнего контура у 3D модели) и разместить в него этот ответ. К сожалению *здесь* ответ уже не подходит и может быть заминусован / удален.

Answer (score 0):

С текущими условиями, вам нужно смотреть в сторону двухпроходного рендера:

1. Подготовить фрейм-буфер размером с окно рендеринга и прицепить к нему текстуру.
2. Отрендерить в буфер/текстуру нормали сцены первым проходом (что-то типа `color.rgb = normal.xyz`) (со включенным тестом глубины).
3. Вторым проходом рендерите эту текстуру 1в1 и рассчитываете наличие ребра по нормалям (смотрите нормали соседних пикселей, отстоящие на `1.0 / ширина_текстуры`)